# How to declare Var outside of for loop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, null, instance

I have an `else` block containing two `for loops`.

With the second for loop I am trying to create a set of `objectYouCreate` instances from a clean slate, as in if a set of instances was previously made, it was already successfully destroyed via the first for loop. So each time this code runs (in the `Update` method), it is creating an entirely new set of instances after wiping the previous set.

This is the (could be flawed) logic I came up with to do that, but I'm getting this error:

Error: `"Cannot assign <null> to implicitly typed variable"`

Can I receive help with how to best restructure this code logically and without errors. Thank you.

```
  else{
        var objectYouCreate = null; //gives the error
        for (int i = 0; i < mesh.vertexCount; i++)
        {
            Destroy(objectYouCreate);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mesh.vertexCount; i++)
        {
            Vector3 position = mesh.vertices[i];                
            objectYouCreate = Instantiate(CubePrefab, position, transform.rotation);
        }
     }
```

__

edit:

By introducing usage of tags to my code... I was able to change the code so that the only `var` declaration happens inside a single for loop and is not null.

I'm also trying to utilize the tags for the Destroy portion, so that it does not just focus the same object but instead focuses all objects with the given tag upon instantiate. But this new code crashes Unity! If anyone has suggestions for optimization or a different method please let me know.

```
    else
    {
        while (GameObject.FindWithTag("CubePFInst") != null) Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("CubePFInst"));

        for (int i = 0; i < mesh.vertexCount; i++)
        {
            Vector3 position = mesh.vertices[i];                
            var cubeClone = Instantiate(CubePrefab, position, transform.rotation);
            cubeClone.tag = "CubePFInst";
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Cannot assign <null> to implicitly typed variable* ... well then maybe you should use **explicity typed variable** ... the error is self-explanatory as obviously compiler cannot guess type of the null ... edit: ... also this code would have no sens  as you wuld be destroying same object multiple times

Comment: You cannot, declare the object type. `var variableName` works because it knows what type is being assigned `var object = myDataTable.Rows[0];`

Comment: `var` in C# is different from `var` in Javascript. In the former it´s a **compile**-time-type like any other. However `null` has no type at all, making it impossible to infer the actual type **at compile-time**.

Comment: @Selvin I tried to change the code so it does not focus the same object. But this new code crashes Unity. If you have further suggestions please let me know. `else
        {
            while (GameObject.FindWithTag("CubePFInst") != null) Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("CubePFInst"));

            for (int i = 0; i < mesh.vertexCount; i++)
            {
                Vector3 position = mesh.vertices[i];                
                var cubeClone = Instantiate(CubePrefab, position, transform.rotation);
                cubeClone.tag = "CubePFInst";
            }
        }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`var` was introduced for compile-time type-binding for anonymous types yet we can use `var` for primitive and custom types that are already known at design time. At runtime there's nothing like `var`, it is replaced by an actual type that is either a reference type or value type.

References:

- [var (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var)
- https://www.itorian.com/2015/04/initialize-var-with-null-or-empty-in-c.html

Comment: Consider changing the link for one that is going to be long live like [Microsoft official documentation - var keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var)

Comment: What is the use of `var objectYouCreate = new { };`?

Comment: Remove the "Solution" part and it would be a better answer than now.

Comment: If `objectYouCreate = Instantiate(CubePrefab, position, transform.rotation);` then `var objectYouCreate = new { };` makes no sense. It should be  `ReturnTypeOfInstantiate objectYouCreate = null;`